# Approximate $\int^1_0 e^{-x^2}\,dx$.

Tags: real-analysis, numerical-methods

> Compute $\int^1_0 e^{-x^2}\,dx$ to three decimal places.

The answer is $0.747$, but I get $0.746$. Here is my argument.

Since
$$
\begin{split}
e^x      &= \sum^5_{n=0}\frac{x^n}{n!}+o(x^5)\text{,} \\
e^{-x^2} &= \sum^5_{n=0}(-1)^n\frac{x^{2n}}{n!}+o(x^{10})\text{.}
\end{split}
$$
Since
$$
\frac{x^{2n}}{n!}\frac{(n+1)!}{x^{2n+2}}=\frac{n+1}{x^2}>1
$$
for $0<x<1$,
$$
\sum^5_{n=0}(-1)^n\frac{x^{2n}}{n!}<e^{-x^2}<\sum^5_{n=0}(-1)^n\frac{x^{2n}}{n!}+\frac{x^{12}}{6!}\text{.}
$$
Hence
$$
1-\frac1{3}+\frac1{10}-\frac1{42}+\frac1{216}-\frac1{1320}
 < \int^1_0e^{-x^2}\,dx
 < -\frac1{3}+\frac1{10}-\frac1{42}+\frac1{216}-\frac1{1320} + \frac1{9360}
$$
According to calculator,
$$
1 - \frac1{3} + \frac1{10} - \frac1{42} + \frac1{216} - \frac1{1320}
\approx 0.7467291967291968
$$
and
$$
1/9360\approx0.00010
$$
So who is coorect?

Comment: What you wrote rounds to $0.747$.

Answer (score 1):

Double checking part of your calculations, I find:
$$ 1 - \dfrac{1}{3} + \dfrac{1}{42} + \dfrac{1}{210} - \dfrac{1}{1320} \approx 0.7468 $$
This rounds to $0.747$. Your method looks correct to me. Therefore, I believe your work is correct.

Notice that if you did one more term it would be positive and it would increase the value of your answer. As such, you may want to redo your work with one additional term.

Answer (score 1):

Several numerical integration techniques can be used to approximate:

$$\int_0^1 e^{-x^2} dx$$

Perhaps the most straightforward to understand is the trapezoidal rule, whereby the function is approximated on the interval with evenly-spaced trapezoids underneath the curve.  The approximation formula is given by:

$$I = (b - a)\frac{f(x_0) + 2\sum_{i = 1}^{n-1}f(x_i) + f(x_n)}{2n} $$

where I is the integral estimate, n is the number of trazezoids, and a and b are the limits of integration.

For example, with four trapezoids, this calculation becomes:

$$I = (1 - 0)\frac{e^{-0^2} + 2(e^{-0.25^2} + e^{-0.50^2} + e^{-0.75^2}) + e^{-1^2}}{(2*4)} \approx  0.7429840978$$

Since the calculation is unreasonable to conduct by hand, numerical methods most commonly use a computer language function or program.  Using an R language algorithm with one million trapezoids, the function is approximated by $$I = 0.7468241328124$$

Because all of the figures reported here are significant (this is easily checked with a separate algorithm), the integral clearly rounds to 0.747.  Rounding to three decimal places, your answer is correct.